# Sum netchanges between shapshots in transactional fact

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a transactional fact with irregular effective from and effectiveTo dates with cumulative total and net changes over ID and time.

Now I want to sum the net changes between two snapshots, for example 2012-01-01 and 2015-07-01 that should include all the rows including and between the snapshot dates.

I would like to select the relevant rows using the snapshot dates so that I can perform a sum on NC_Total grouped on ID.

What is the most efficient way to to this? Can I create a table valued function for this?

This is how the table looks selected for ID IN (1,2):

[image: Here is a shot of the transactional table]

This is the resultset I should get back using the snapshot dates:

[Select rows on snapshot date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09YGS.png)

And this is how I would like to finally sum it:

[Sum of snapshot dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmcxG.png)

Comment: Please provide examples of the results you want.

Comment: You say you want to sum, so it would seem the best place to start would be to look at the [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

Comment: The problem is not with the sum, but with the selection of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want inequalities in a `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where effectiveTo >= '2012-01-01' and 
      startFrom <= '2015-06-01'
```

Then you can use aggregation:

```
select id, sum(nc_total) as sum_net_changes
from t
where effectiveTo >= '2012-01-01' and 
      startFrom <= '2015-06-01'
```

Comment: Since the snapshots are between the EffectiveFrom and the EffectiveTo dates this returns no rows.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up writing a table valued function for this but the gist of the selection had less to do with SQL than with thinking about the datelogic. The solution was not as elegant as I would have wanted:

DECLARE @t1 DATETIME = '2012-01-01'

DECLARE @t2 DATETIME = '2015-07-01'

AND (EffectiveFrom >= @t1 AND EffectiveFrom <= @t2) -- All transactions between the snapshots